# Do NRF24L01 modules have to use the same SCK-Frequency to work together?

Tags: spi, nrf24l01

I have two Atmega 328p Microcontrollers connected to NRF24l01 modules. The first one uses a SCK-Frequency of 2Mhz and the second one a SCK-Frequency of 4Mhz. 
Sadly the Connection doesn't seem to be working.

Do both modules have to use the same SCK-Frequency to work together? Why or why not?

Comment: SPI has a master-slave architecture, the master sets the clock speed and the slave follows provided its maximum frequency is not exceeded. I assume each microcontroller is the master for one RF module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have to use the same frequencies. SCK frequency determines how fast the master (your Atmega 328p) can read/write from the nRF24. It does not determine how the nRF is configured or what is the over-the-air speed.

It may make a difference only if your are sending **LOTS** of data from a master that uses faster SCK and the master with slower SCK just can't read it fast enough. A logic analyzer (even the $8 kind) helps a lot with SPI debugging.